# javascript replace with regex img tag with specific id but other attributes could be anything

Tags: javascript, regex

Embarrassed to ask, since I should be able to get this, but I've been hitting my head against the wall for a while. I need to replace an img element with a known unique id (here, say, id="abc123"). I would think this should do it, but apparently I'm wrong:

```
var rgx = '/<img[^>]*id="abc123"[^>]*>/';
var replaced_text = edata.replace(rgx, myreplacementstring);
```

where edata is a big chunk of html, and myreplacementstring is what I want to replace the img element with. I know in advance that the image element to replace is all lower case, but of course there will be other attributes beyond the id, and they could be on either side of the id. Should be easy right? What am I missing?

Comment: if the img has an id attribute then why not just use getElementById? (id's should be unique on each page).

Comment: /<img[^>]*?id="abc123"[^>]*>/ does not seem to work.

Comment: How do you define 'does not seem to work'? Is it doing any replace? Is the replace wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression works fine.

What you need to do is this:

```
var rgx = /<img[^>]*id="abc123"[^>]*>/;
```

instead of:

```
var rgx = '/<img[^>]*id="abc123"[^>]*>/';
```

You can see your code working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/bMKLU/

Comment: Yes, you're right so I'll accept of course. Thanks. For the record this wasn't quite enough for my case (which I didn't spell out fully). My regex replace was happening on success of a jquery ajax call, and the regex is what is returned from the server. So it was already in a variable, and so no way to unquote it and thus it wouldn't work for me to just pass it in to replace like: `var replaced_text = edata.replace(rgx, myreplacementstring);` Instead I had to do: `var gvaregex = new RegExp(rgx,\"g\");` and then `edata.replace(gvaregex, gvareplace);`

Comment: @jimb Glad I could help and that you also fixed the further problem you found (good work in including what you did to get around your problem in your previous comment too).